# Verifying Signature that was generated in JS does not succeed in Python

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography

I am creating the keys using javascript like this

```
// Generate P-256 key pair
        const keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            {
                name: 'ECDSA',
                namedCurve: 'P-256'
            },
            true,
            ['sign']
        );
```

I am then signing a message using the Key like this

```
let transaction = {
            sender: address,
            recipient: recipient,
            amount: amount
        };
        
        // Convert the transaction data to a JSON string
        let dataString = JSON.stringify(transaction);

        // Calculate the hash of the transaction data
        let data_hash = arrayBufferToHex(await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', new TextEncoder().encode(dataString)));

        // Sign the hash
        const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
            {
                name: 'ECDSA',
                hash: { name: 'SHA-256' }
            },
            keyPair,
            hexToArrayBuffer(data_hash)
        );

        // Convert the signature to hex
        const signatureHex = arrayBufferToHex(signature);

        // Add the signature and original data hash to the transaction
        transaction.signature = signatureHex;
        transaction.hash = data_hash;
```

I am sending this transaction + public key to a Python Backend where I am trying to verify it like this

```
from ecdsa import VerifyingKey, SECP256k1
from binascii import unhexlify

def verify(public_key, signature, data_hash):
    """
    Verify a signature.
    :param public_key: The public key of the signer.
    :param signature: The signature to be verified.
    :param data_hash: The hash of the data that was signed.
    """
    # Convert the public key to bytes
    public_key_bytes = unhexlify(public_key)

    # Convert the signature to bytes
    signature_bytes = unhexlify(signature)

    # Convert the data hash to bytes
    data_hash = unhexlify(data_hash)

    # Create a verifying key from the public key
    verifying_key = VerifyingKey.from_string(public_key_bytes, curve=SECP256k1)

    # Verify the signature
    is_valid = verifying_key.verify(signature_bytes, data_hash)

    print(f"Signature is valid: {is_valid}")

    

    return is_valid
```

Results in ecdsa.errors.MalformedPointError: Point does not lay on the curve

I tried so much and I dont know whats wrong. I also used the cryptography package but that also fails when verifying signature.

Comment: I think P256 and SECP256K1 are different elliptic curves.   This explains your error message.

Comment: I’m now sure of my previous answer. P256 is secp256r1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded answer.

p-256 is [secp256r1](https://neuromancer.sk/std/secg/secp256r1). This is a completely different curve from [secp256k1](https://neuromancer.sk/std/x963/ansip256k1). The only thing they have in common is 256 bits.

A public key is a point on the elliptic curve. JS is generating a point on the first curve, and that’s not a point on the second curve.

The error message is telling you this.